# QAbstractItemView asks model for invalid index

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qt5

I'm writting a program using Qt5 which works fine on Linux but on Windows I was observing strange behaviour:

When `QTreeView::setModel` was called, it asked model for index (`QAbstractItemModel::index`) with some row and col and invalid parent.
It never happend on Linux, view always asked for `hasChildren`, `rowCount` etc before calling `index`.

I've downloaded Qt5's sources to see what's going on and I can see:

```
// These asserts do basic sanity checking of the model
Q_ASSERT_X(d->model->index(0,0) == d->model->index(0,0),
           "QAbstractItemView::setModel",
           "A model should return the exact same index "
           "(including its internal id/pointer) when asked for it twice in a row.");
Q_ASSERT_X(!d->model->index(0,0).parent().isValid(),
           "QAbstractItemView::setModel",
           "The parent of a top level index should be invalid");
```

I cannot find a single word about those sanity checks in documentation of view classes nor model classes.

Where are they defined?

Another interesting thing here is that I could deduce by observation of model/view classes I've written that top index should be invalid but I couldn't find this information directly in docs.

Comment: The problem is probably in your model. The `index` function in your model is not implemented correctly, at least not suitable for `QTreeView`. Messages in those assertions clearly describe the requirements.

Comment: what do you mean by not implemented correctly? I didn't mean I get those assertions. I just wondered whey view asks for indexes in an empty model without making sure there is something before asking for index of nonexistent item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [`QAbstractItemModel::parent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#parent):

> If the item has no parent, an invalid QModelIndex is returned.

This means that calling `index()` with an invalid QModelIndex asks for top level items.

The sanity checks you encountered may have been disabled in Linux (maybe release build?) - but your model's functionality should in no way depend on the order of function calls.

If `index()` is called with invalid row / column parameters (also if your model is not populated yet), return `QModelIndex()`.